# Oracle SQL outer join query puzzle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join

```
select
  whatever
from
  bank_accs b1,
  bank_accs b2,
  table3 t3
where
  t3.bank_acc_id = t1.bank_acc_id and
  b2.bank_acc_number = b1.bank_acc_number and
  b2.currency_code(+) = t3.buy_currency and
  trunc(sysdate) between nvl(b2.start_date, trunc(sysdate)) and nvl(b2.end_date, trunc(sysdate));
```

My problem is with the date (actuality) check on b2. Now, I need to return a row for each t3xb1 (t3 = ~10 tables joined, of course), even if there are ONLY INVALID records (date-wise) in b2. How do I outer-join this bit properly?
Can't use ANSI joins, must do in a single flat query.
Thanks.

Comment: why can't you use explicit joins? YOu can stioll do it in one query. There is not reason why they can't be used ever. Infact, you should not ever be using implicit joins, theya rean antiptternand 20 uyears out of date.

Comment: A query using explicit ansi `JOIN`s is still "*a single flat query*"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, just add the outer sign(+) to all columns of b2:

```
select
  whatever
from
  bank_accs b1,
  bank_accs b2,
  table3 t3
where
  t3.bank_acc_id = t1.bank_acc_id and
  b2.bank_acc_number = b1.bank_acc_number and
  b2.currency_code(+) = t3.buy_currency and
  trunc(sysdate) between nvl(b2.start_date(+), trunc(sysdate)) and nvl(b2.end_date(+), trunc(sysdate));
```

Comment: Do not encourage the use of implicit joins which are a SQL antipattern

Comment: user asked explicily for it: "Can't use ANSI joins, must do in a single flat query.". May be a homework, or maybe is a rule in the company for that project.

Comment: @FlorinGhita My bet is on homework, because as a company rule, this doesn't make any sense IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to write old-style outer join with inequalities but it is error-prone. I suggest you use an inline view and the outer join will be clear and explicit:

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM bank_accs b1,
       table3 t3,
       (SELECT b2.*
          FROM bank_accs b2
         WHERE trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN nvl(b2.start_date, trunc(sysdate)) 
                                  AND nvl(b2.end_date, trunc(sysdate))
       ) b2
 WHERE t3.bank_acc_id = t1.bank_acc_id
   AND b2.bank_acc_number = b1.bank_acc_number
   AND b2.currency_code(+) = t3.buy_currency;
```

Comment: It would even be better if changed to use the explicit `JOIN` syntax

Comment: Do not encourage the use of implicit joins which are a SQL antipattern

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name user asked explicily for it: "Can't use ANSI joins, must do in a single flat query."

Comment: @FlorinGhita: that requirement doesn't make sense. A query using ANSI Joins is still "a single query".

Comment: @HLGEM For all I know, the OP's version of Oracle may not support ANSI joins (8i). It could also be a problem with the parser of a tool (like some versions of Oracle reports). Anyway, it's not ideal to work with old-style joins but if you have no choice, my answer provides a simple tip to actually make the SQL readable.